# Angular JS - $q.all() tracking individual upload progress

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, q, angular-file-upload

I'm using `angular-file-upload` module by danialfarid (https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) and it works great.

I've been able to integrate in my wrapper service for REST calls and I can actually upload several images with `$q.all()` and keeping track of their progress.

However, I can't correctly identify the single images I'm uploading, because the file identifier gets continuosly changed by the for loop.

```
      uploadPhotos: function (files) {

        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var queue = []

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          var up = $upload.upload({
            url: locationURI +'/photos',
            file: file,
            fileFormDataName: 'image'
          }).then(
            function (data) {
              console.log(data)
            },
            function (err) {
              console.log(err)
            },
            function(evt) {
              // progress events
              console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            }
          )
          queue.push(up)
        }

        $q.all(queue).then(
          function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data)
          },
          function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
          }
        )

        return deferred.promise
      }
```

This is, without any surprise, the confused output I get:

```
    percent: 68 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 14 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 37 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 52 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 89 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
    percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
```

Do you have any idea how could I manage to have something like:

```
    file1 - percent: 68 restfactory.js:359
    file1 - percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
    file2 - percent: 100 restfactory.js:359
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closures within loops are tricky. Closing on the loop variable will always get the last value (e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) - and google it for more theory/details). What you want would be to call another function within the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var up = doTheUpload(files[i]);
    queue.push(up);
}
```

And `doTheUpload()` contains your original code, returning the promise and using the correct `file` (I do *not* know the API, I presume `file.name` is contains the file name; adjust appropriately):

```
function doTheUpload(file) {
      var up = $upload.upload({
        url: locationURI +'/photos',
        file: file,
        fileFormDataName: 'image'
      }).then(
        function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err)
        },
        function(evt) {
          // progress events
          console.log(file.name + ' percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        }
      );
      return up;
}
```

Comment: I was just writing it, beat me to it ;)

Comment: Damn, it was easy. I guess I've finally learned something about closures today!